# Show/hide multiple children classes for an individual parent click (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm fairly new to Javascript/Jquery and I'm trying to hide multiple children/adjacent classes when a specific parent class is clicked.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class ="col-md-2 pov_icon">
     <div class="pov_icon_small">
      <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="pov_title_small">
       MEASURE
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="col-md-2 pov_icon">
     <div class="pov_icon_large">
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="pov_title_large">
       MEASURE
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class ="col-md-2 pov_icon">
     <div class="pov_icon_small">
      <i class="fa fa-commenting"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="pov_title_small">
       MEASURE
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I'm aiming to do is: When a user clicks one of the two smaller icons shown (pov_icon_small), for that individual icon: the classes `pov_icon_small` and `pov_title_small` will change to `pov_icon_large` and `pov_title_large`  respectively. In the same time, I want the other 'large' icon and 'title' to revert back to the 'small' state

I've started calling some Javascript but I don't think I'm headed the right way:

```
$('.pov_icon_small').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("pov_icon_large");
});
```

Would anyone be willing to point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To use individual click**

```
$('.pov_icon_small , .pov_icon_large').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.pov_icon_large').not($(this)).removeClass('pov_icon_large').addClass('pov_icon_small');
    $(this).toggleClass("pov_icon_small").toggleClass("pov_icon_large");
});
```

and for title the same way

```
$('.pov_title_small , .pov_title_large').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.pov_title_large').not($(this)).removeClass('pov_title_large').addClass('pov_title_small'); 
    $(this).toggleClass("pov_title_small").toggleClass("pov_title_large");
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/aL9xxdkw/1/)

**To run both action on icon click use this**

```
$('.pov_icon_small , .pov_icon_large').on('click', function () {
    $('.pov_icon_large').not($(this)).removeClass('pov_icon_large').addClass('pov_icon_small');
    $('.pov_title_large').not($(this).next('div[class^="pov_title_"]')).removeClass('pov_title_large').addClass('pov_title_small'); 
    $(this).toggleClass("pov_icon_small").toggleClass("pov_icon_large");
    $(this).next('div[class^="pov_title_"]').toggleClass("pov_title_small").toggleClass("pov_title_large");
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/aL9xxdkw/2/)

> Note: be sure to include Jquery

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a common class icon for the icon div and title for the title div and following code will work,

```
     $(".pov_icon_small").on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().siblings().children('div').each(function(value){
            if($(this).hasClass('icon'))
              $(this).addClass('pov_icon_small').removeClass('pov_icon_large');
            else if($(this).hasClass('title'))
              $(this).addClass('pov_title_small').removeClass('pov_title_large');

        });

        $(this).addClass('pov_icon_large').removeClass('pov_icon_small');
        $(this).siblings('.title').addClass('pov_title_large').removeClass('pov_title_small');
      });
```

Here as you can see, I am first getting parent of the icon clicked i.e. Your pav_icon div now I am changing for all the siblings now each div in the sibling. If it is Iicon changing icon classes as required if title changing title classes.